# Checar el nuevo valor de una variable en un action

Tags: c#, pruebas-unitarias

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código de una prueba unitaria:

```
[Test]
public void ValidCancel_ReturnsSuccess()
{
    // TODO: Rewrite this action to really check the cancel
    bool cancel;
    var message =
        new MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage<string>(this, "Test", () => cancel = true);

    Assert.IsNotNull(message.Sender);
    Assert.IsNotNull(message.Content);
}
```

`MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage` es un constructor que recibe un `sender`, un `content` y un `Action` a realizar como argumentos. En el tercer argumento estoy cambiando la variable `cancel` a `true`. El detalle aquí es que si quiero hacer un `Assert.IsTrue` de la variable trae `false`. ¿Existe alguna manera para checar ese cambio en la variable, o no es posible?

Esta es la clase que estoy probando:

```
using System;

public abstract class MessageHubMessageBase : IMessageHubMessage
{
    private readonly WeakReference _sender;

    protected MessageHubMessageBase(object sender)
    {
        if (sender == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sender));

        _sender = new WeakReference(sender);
    }

    public object Sender => _sender?.Target;
}

public class MessageHubGenericMessage<TContent>
    : MessageHubMessageBase
{
    public MessageHubGenericMessage(object sender, TContent content)
        : base(sender)
    {
        Content = content;
    }

    public TContent Content { get; protected set; }
}

public class MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage<TContent> 
    : MessageHubMessageBase
{
    public MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage(object sender, TContent content, Action cancelAction)
        : base(sender)
    {
        Content = content;
        Cancel = cancelAction ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cancelAction));
    }

    public Action Cancel { get; protected set; }

    public TContent Content { get; protected set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Quieres saber si el valor se cambió antes de llamar al Assert?

Puedes colocar puntos de interrupción después de la llamada al constructor, y puedes inspeccionar el valor de la variable Cancel.

¿Quieres saber si entra al Action y en que momento lo hace? puedes cambiar de:

```
var message =
    new MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage<string>(
        this, "Unosquare Américas", 
        () => cancel = true);
```

a:

```
var message =
    new MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage<string>(
        this, "Unosquare Américas", 
        () => 
        {  // <-- coloca un punto de iterrupción aquí
            cancel = true; 
        });
```

Y la ejecución del programa se va a pausar ahí, y con F10 puedes avanzar instrucción por instrucción para ver el valor de cancel.

**EDIT**: Por cierto, no veo en que momento, en el código, lances la llamada al action.

No se si olvidaste poner esa parte del código, pero creo que sería algo así:

```
public class MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage<TContent> : MessageHubMessageBase
{
    public MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage(object sender, TContent content, Action cancelAction) : base(sender)
    {
        Content = content;
        Cancel = cancelAction ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cancelAction));

        Cancel(); // <--- esta línea debe ir donde quieres llamar al action
    }

    public Action Cancel { get; protected set; }

    public TContent Content { get; protected set; }
}
```

Igual no entendí el propósito del Action.

Comment: Creo que te capto. Poner un Assert.IsTrue() después de la definición de la variable. Lo de la invocación lo checaré.

Comment: Si, también un Assert.IsTrue(cancel) te ayudará.

Answer (score -1):

> ¿Existe alguna manera para checar ese cambio en la variable, o no es posible?

Sí, es con `Assert.IsTrue`, tal como lo hicistes.

> El detalle aquí es que si quiero hacer un `Assert.IsTrue` de la variable trae `false`.

Esto es porque `cancel` nunca pasa a `true`.

> En el tercer argumento estoy cambiando la variable `cancel` a `true`.

No, y aquí está el problema.  En el tercer argumento le estás pasando código en la forma de un `Action` que, ***si alguien fuera a ejecutarlo***, entonces cambiaría la variable a `true`. Pero nadie lo ejecuta. Si examinamos el código del constructor de la clase `MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage<TContent>`:

```
public class MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage<TContent> 
    : MessageHubMessageBase
{
    public MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage(object sender, TContent content, Action cancelAction)
        : base(sender)
    {
        Content = content;
        Cancel = cancelAction ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cancelAction));
    }

    public Action Cancel { get; protected set; }

    public TContent Content { get; protected set; }
}
```

... podemos ver que el parámetro `Action cancelAction` es asignado a la propiedad `Cancel`. Pero no hay nada que ejecute el `Action`, de forma que la sentencia `cancel = true` nunca es ejecutada.

Si quieres que se ejecute, para poder luego comprobar que la variable `cancel` cambió, debes agregar una llamada a `message.Cancel()` en tu prueba unitaria:

```
[Test]
public void ValidCancel_ReturnsSuccess()
{
    // TODO: Rewrite this action to really check the cancel
    bool cancel;
    var message =
        new MessageHubCancellableGenericMessage<string>(this, "Test", () => cancel = true);

    // Esta sentencia cambia cancel a true.
    message.Cancel();

    // Ahora sí puedes verificar que la variable cambió
    Assert.IsTrue(cancel);

    Assert.IsNotNull(message.Sender);
    Assert.IsNotNull(message.Content);
}
```